# Stretching circle width from the layer weight node inside a sphere

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

I want to stretch the black part of the eye to a lower width without changing the height. I don't know if this is the right approach to do it, but I hope someone can help! Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image: I want to stretch the black part of the eye to a lower width without changing the height. I don't know if this is the right approach to do it, but I hope someone can help! Thank you in advance.]

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a `Texture Co-ordinate` node connected with the *Object output* to the mapping node, connect it to the *Normal* of the `Layer Weight` and play with the `scale` values:

[image]

If you have the *Node Wrangler* Addon, you could just press `Ctrl` + `T` to add the `Texture Co-ordinate` and `Mapping` node automatically.

Comment: The problem is when you rotate the camera. Sorry should have said that in the post just thought i did it wrong.
I don't know if it is possible to make in another way?